# Device is not connecting - Xcode Version 6.1.1 Using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Whenever I have connected my iPad device to my Xcode (6.1.1), am getting this kind of error,

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x344ac614> {
    count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x344ac86c> {
        length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted"
    }
}>
```

Kindly help me get out of this issue.

Comment: are u using adhoc provisioning profile , if yes then better to use development provisioning profile .

Comment: Am using development provisioning profile only

Comment: as far as XPC is concerned ..make sure you have clean the project properly and if it possible restart it . it will automatically solve.